# Android activity navigation loop

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm writing an Android 4.X app.

Most of the activities work in a tree-structure (so the stack is perfect for them) and 'back' works as expected.

I have a loop in my activity design

```
 -> list messages -> view message -> ack -> reply -
|                                                  |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

This will accumulate activities on the stack.

How do I make the completion of a reply kill itself and the 'ack' and 'view message' activities from the stack, instead of creating a new 'list message' activity?

Is this the correct way to resolve a navigation loop in an Android app?

Comment: Don't know if this is the best way to do it, but you could start every activity with result, and when you finish the reply activity you can tell the ack activity to close itself after telling its parent activity to do the same and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do startActivityForResult(Intent intent); and onActivityResult() you can do stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example for anyone who needs it...

ListMessages

```
    public void next() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewMessages.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

ViewMessages

```
    public void next() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AckMessage.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
        finish();
    }
```

AckMessage

```
    public void next() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReplyMessage.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
```

ReplyMessage

```
    public void complete() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have another simple solution for your problem.
From your last activity in the loop. You can start the first activity with those of flags :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

It will remove all activities above your FirstActivity from stack. And onNewIntent() method will be called in FirstActivity.

You can check more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)